# How to loop through each word in a line of a file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The content of `text.txt` is:

```
absolute abstract academic accepted accident
```

I'm trying to loop through each word and print it so I can get an output like this:

```
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```

I tried using `cat` but it starts from the field `1` so it end up ignoring a word

```
words="$(cat text.txt | wc -w)"

for ((i=0; i<$words; i++)); do

        cut -d' ' -f$i text.txt

done
```

I think `awk` could also be useful but I don't know very well its syntax.

```
awk '{print $'$i'}'
```

I tried something like this but the output was a mess.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Regarding `I'm trying to loop through each word` - please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You over-complicate it, bash `for` loop can go through a list of words:

```
for word in $(cat text.txt); do
  echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: It's giving me an error `$word': not a valid identifier`

Comment: I've updatet the syntax a bit ("), check out this way pls.

Comment: Have a look at why you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way without loop:

```
$ tr ' ' $'\n' < file
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```

or using `printf` and *word splitting*:

```
printf '%s\n' $(<file)
```

or using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g' file
```

or using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/g' file
```

Comment: The `tr ...`  solution works only if the file has sctrictly one space between the words.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU grep & sed):

```
grep -o '\S\+' file
```

or:

```
sed -n 's/\>\s*/\n/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
absolute abstract academic accepted accident
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row are separated by one-or-more (`+`) whitespace characters, then each row is `print`ed using default output row separator, which is newline character.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

If you prefer GNU `sed` then you might simply do

```
sed 'y/ /\n/' file.txt
```

where sole command given mean replace each space using newline character, output is same as above

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xargs -n 1 echo < text.txt
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' text.txt
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```

Answer (score 0):

any of these solutions are also valid on the other 2 `awk` variants listed :

```
echo 'absolute abstract academic accepted accident ' |
```

> ```
> nawk NF=NF OFS='\n'
>
> gawk 3 RS='[[:space:]]+'
>
> mawk 7 RS='[\n\r ]+'
> ```

```
absolute
abstract
academic
accepted
accident
```